# How to put an image or icon over a pushButton

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

Can anyone help me with putting an image or icon on a push button?
I tried with a style sheet but that's not working. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qpushbutton constructor says.
QPushButton ( const QIcon & icon, const QString & text, QWidget * parent = 0 );

```
QPushButton *pushme = new QPushButton (QIcon(":/new/prefix1/Sunset.jpg"),"Test");
pushme->setGeometry(20,20,50,40);
pushme->show();
```

give the specific width and height of icon, based on your convince in setgeometry.

Comment: Thanks for ur sudden reply..
Her ei am getting error..QIcon identifier not found and setsetgeometry not a member of QPushButton..... I included QIcon in header

Comment: @sijith *setgeometry* not a member, but *setGeometry* is! Plz, read docs first.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a more flexible way of doing it:

```
myPushButton->setIcon(QIcon);
```